# one definition, two functions

Tags: functions

I have two function definitions that look almost the same, one is to show the animation in MMA and the other one is to export the frames so that I can use ImageJ to combine to a video. I found this way, export and use other software to generate video, is much much faster than ask MMA to export a video. I wonder is there an elegant way to combine these two function definitions into one. The input data is from a **CSV** file and of the format: `{{x,y},…}`. Sometimes the input data can have thousands of lines. The differences between the two functions are shown as comments below.

BTW, I found using Animate seems to me faster than list all the frames and stitch together using ListAnimate. If is there any way to improve the speed, please let me know.

Thank you.

```
myAnim1[data_,color_,xLabel_String,yLabel_String,unit_String]:=Module[{g,plotRange,xRange,yRange},
g=ListLinePlot[data,PlotRange->All];
plotRange=g~AbsoluteOptions~#~OptionValue~#&[PlotRange];
{xRange,yRange}=-Subtract@@@plotRange;

    Animate(*ParallelTable when export frames*)[
        Show[
        ListLinePlot[data[[1;;n]],
        PlotStyle->color,
        PlotRange->plotRange,
        Frame->True,
        FrameTicks->All,
        FrameStyle->Directive[FontSize->16],
        FrameLabel->{xLabel,yLabel},    
        PlotRangeClipping->False,
        ImagePadding->Outer[Times,{60,50},{1,1}]],      
        Graphics[
        {Red,PointSize[0.01],Point[data[[n]]],
        Text[Style[ToString@Round[data[[n,2]],.1]<>" "<>unit,Italic,FontSize->14,Background->White],data[[n]]+{0,.04*yRange}]}
        ],
        
        ImageSize->{900,600}
        ],
        
        {n,1,Length@data,1},
(* The following options should be gone when export frames *)
        DefaultDuration->30(*sec*),
        AnimationRunning->False,
        AnimationDirection->Forward,
        AnimationRepetitions->1
        ]
];
```

Comment: Suppose you add one extra argument to your function. That is going to control which of your two actions you want it to do. You test that argument inside your function, perhaps using `If` or `Which` and then your function uses or doesn't use your extra options. Does that give you enough of a hint that you can experiment and see if you can make this work?

Comment: @Bill, Thanks for the suggestions, I used the ```If``` to switch between ```ParallelTable``` and ```Animate```. However, I am stuck on including the options of Animate. Could you please give more hints on that? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that ```Animate``` has ```HoldAll``` attribute. Now the problem is solved. Thanks.